# Not getting output in Selenium for chrome browser -- Attached output image

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, validation, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOKtS.png)

my selenium  is old thats why this error is occored ? i can't understand

package browserbasics;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Browsers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");
    

}
```

}